# Entities with JHipster generated automatically

Tags: jhipster

I'm studing JHipster and try to create few entities with relationships. But when I started generated new entity

```
yo jhipster:entity blog
```

entity blog generated automatically without any configuration questions.
How it possible? Before I do it without any problem, and I got all configuration questions.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you have created entity "blog" before. Try to check .jhipster/ directory into your project. All config information about entities jhipster saved in json files. You should delete "blog.json" and try again.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it started re generating your already existing entity. Make sure you ave deleted the respective entity's json file before creating the entity with same name.

Another alternative is to create an entity with different name say blogger, blogs
like that